# c++, OSX 10.9, QT 5.3, SDL2, ,my shared library does not link if I use it

Tags: c++, macos, qt, sdl

I have a "small" problem, I use SDL in my shared library and I link it there and I can build the library without any error message in QT on a OS X 10.9.

Now if I want to use my shared library in an App project and I link just the my shared library, I get an error message "SDL2/SDL.h" not found in a header file of my shared library. But I can build the library on its own but when I want to use it I get this include error?

Any suggestions?

Thank you!!

Comment: Show us your build command lines.

Comment: Technically this question is not about linking, but rather compiling.  When you try to build your app you should add paths to _header files_  not only from your library but also to all third party libraries that are used directly or indirectly in the app

Comment: So add paths to SDL headers to the compiler invocation line.